# lexicographic comparison of strings [case-insensitive]

Tags: c++, string, sorting, case-insensitive, lexicographic

I want to sort the text of a file in lexicographic order but I'm having trouble understand what lexicographic order really does.

Ordering strings produces another issue; the relational operators use ASCII values so

`betty < Diane` is false when it should be true .

Consider a sample list : 
betty, Diane, 123, Ana, Megan, charles, two, 12.

How would I set that in lexicographic order?

Comment: It's easier than you think: [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is already using lexicographic comparison.

Comment: What do you mean by that? @ someprogrammerdude

Comment: Try implementing your own Radix Sort if you want to learn instead of making things easier by using STL.

Comment: its not like im asking for code lol, just wanted some explanation

Answer (score 2):

Approach:

1. Use `map <convert_to_lower_case(words) as string, index as integer>` to put all the words in the list.
2. After that create a sorted vector `myVec` using:

   `for(it_type iterator = m.begin(); iterator != m.end(); iterator++) {
          myVec.push_back(original_list[it->second]);
    }`

`myVec` is the lexicographically sorted list you are looking for.
You need to implement `convert_to_lower_case(word)` :

```
for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
  word[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}
```

Other answer is good too, uses comparator to sort the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not do what you want?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> v {"Diane", "123", "Ana", "Megan", "charles", "two", "12"};

  for (const auto& s : v) {
    std::cout << s << ' ';
  };
  std::cout << '\n';

  std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < std::min(a.size(), b.size()) ; i++) {
      const auto a_char = std::tolower(a[i]);
      const auto b_char = std::tolower(b[i]);
      if (a_char != b_char) {
        return a_char < b_char;
      }
    }
    return a.size() < b.size();
  });

  for (const auto& s : v) {
    std::cout << s << ' ';
  };
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

stdout looks like this:

```
Diane 123 Ana Megan charles two 12 
12 123 Ana charles Diane Megan two
```

Comment: This is wrong. Not a case -insensitive search. Read the complete ques.

Answer (score 0):

Use compareToIgnoreCase Method